# CakePHP shows 500 Internal Server Error when project running locally then showing this type of error

Tags: php, cakephp, server, cakephp-3.0

CakePHP Version: 2.9

I Have set database in App/Config/database.php , when the project i am running locally then showing this type of error

my.htaccess file like below

```conf
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
        #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://bdhonda.local:8082/$1 [R,L]
        RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
        RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Any Idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked what error are you getting in your logs.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and the error message you are facing

Comment: Also, keep in mind that v2.9 of CakePHP is horribly outdated. It haas seen its last update in 2017

Comment: "500 Internal Server Error" is a generic error message informing you that the server crashed while processing the request. Beyond that, it's (intentionally) meaningless, and is of very little use for debugging, diagnosing or resolving problems. You need to check the error logs on the server (or enable on-screen error reporting, if it's a development environment) to try and find the underlying exception message. Once you've got that, you stand a chance of identifying the problem, and then moving on to trying to fix it.